# Влияние через RecyclerView Adapter на элементы не являющиеся компонентами списка

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter

Как получить доступ в `RecycleView Adapter` к элементам которые не являются компонентами списка `Recycle View`. Пробовал старым дедовским способом но пишет ошибку 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.CardView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference` Как получить к им доступ не делая их элементами списка?
Например: хочу сделать RecyclerView в котором отображается список после нажатия не видимым, но выбивает выше упомянутую ошибку.

Вот смотрите в методе `bind` я беру массив строк беру выбранную позицию и посылаю в html который не является элементов списка как мне по предложному вами коду сделать?

```
public void bind(final Analysys analysys){
        textView.setHtml(analysys.name);
        frame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    html.setHtml(analysys.analysis);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Для этого нужно пробросить какой-нибудь listener в адаптер, который будет определен в экране, на котором нужно изменить данные, при нажатии на элемент списка. Далее приведу примерный код:

Определяем интерфейс (можно в классе адаптера)

```
interface OnElementClickListener {
    void onElementClick(String needHtml);
}
```

Устанавливаем в адаптере элемент этого интерфейса и сеттер для него

```
private OnElementClickListener onElementClickListener;

public void setOnElementClickListener(OnElementClickListener onElementClickListener) {
    this.onElementClickListener = onElementClickListener;
}
```

Вызываем в адаптере эту функцию таким образом

```
onElementClickListener.onElementClick(item[adapterPosition].getHtml())
```

На экране, на котором устанавливаем данный адаптер, определяем для него этот listener

```
myAdapter.setOnElementClickListener(new MyAdapter.OnElementClickListener() {
    void onElementClick(String needHtml) {
         myTextView.setHtml(needHtml)       
    }
});
```

Comment: Ваш ответ не работает. Ваш метод равен тому если бы я в `Activity` взял на `RecyclerView` поставил метод `onClickListener`